# Can I use the word 'enigma' in reference to a reason why a person did something?

Tags: word-usage

Can I use the word 'enigma' in reference not to a person, but to a reason why he did something?

For example,

> He remained quiet and cagey throughout the whole semester, but on the
> very last day he - to everyone's surprise - bought a cup of coffee for
> each one of us. **Why he would need to do that is still a kind of
> enigma to me to date.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is fine, but the grammar of your sentence doesn't sound natural for a number of reasons.

- How many "kinds" of enigma are there? I think you are trying to use the idiomatic phrase "kind of" meaning *rather*, or *to some extent*.
- You say "still" and then also say "to date", both of which mean the same thing. You should drop one of them.

It should be:

> Why he would need to do that is still kind of an enigma to me.